# Incredible complex solution with 12 projects - failing due to <asp:Login complications

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have recently taken over this application - I did not develop it, and have not ever seen it working. When I run it, I am prompted to login using one of these:

```
<asp:Login controls.
```

Putting breakpoints in the code, I have been able to ascertain that my login is sucessful, but it fails trying to update the file /App_Data/ASPNETDB.MDF. This is my error:

```
 An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\sstaples\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SVSConsole\SVSConsole\Container\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\sstaples\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SVSConsole\SVSConsole\Container\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[SqlException (0x80131904): An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\sstaples\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SVSConsole\SVSConsole\Container\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6749670
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +815
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4515
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +84
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +368
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6777754
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6778255
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +878
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1162
         System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +72
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +6781425
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +103
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2105
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1089
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6785863
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) +150
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +4916462
   System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +1466
   System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +12405373
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.RoleGroup.ContainsUser(IPrincipal user) +81
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.RoleGroupCollection.GetMatchingRoleGroupInternal(IPrincipal user) +113
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView.GetTemplateIndex() +288
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginView.CreateChildControls() +96
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +189
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +60
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4297
```

It took ages and ages to post this, due to the arbitrary posting restrictions on this site. It could be more user friendly!

Comment: Are you sure the said DB exist in it's mentioned path?

Comment: The error message is clear enough. Start by working through the possible causes it lists.

Comment: Yes. DB exists. I can open it using the VS2010 Server Explorer and see aspnet_Users records from the past.

Comment: Are you running it under IIS (OR) VSDEV server? this most probably a permission issue. check this MSKB http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2002980

Comment: I have tried both ways of running it. It fails either way. The error message makes little sense to me. Practically every project on our system uses an ASPNETDB.MDF file, so yes, there are lots of files of that name, in different paths. No idea what UNC share is.